# OneSignal web sdk doesn't work in local host PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

After configure the one signal in my local machine, I put in the head section this piece of code,

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
  window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "app_id_here",
    });
  });
</script>
```

and doesn't show subscription button, and notifications doesn't show also.

Other configurations

- Integration: typical site
- Site url: http://a.test
- label: atest.os.tc

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason is that you need to specify to OneSignal that you are using localhost.

1. Select Typical setup
2. Enter your localhost URL
3. Enable Local Testing (Treat HTTP localhost as HTTPS for testing)

[image]

Come join us in our discord server and learn more about our community and OneSignal: https://onesignal.com/onesignal-developers

Comment: I don't see the option 'LOCAL TESTING' toggle on my setup page

Comment: @Sterko can you post a screenshot on your question, please